# Firebase wait for response

Tags: javascript, firebase

If i have something like this

```js
const query = firebase.database().ref("/posts").orderByChild('postid').equalTo(1);
query.once('value', snapshot=>{
  if(snapshot.val() == "XYZ"){
    console.log("true");
    return true;
  }
});
console.log("false");
return false
```

why is is this printing
false
true

how can i force to wait for the answer of query before jumping to the return false?

Comment: The query is an asynchronous call.

Comment: Probably is console.log("false") after query.once method try put an else in if(snapshot.val() == "XYZ") and inside else put the console.log("false")

Comment: @camden_kid how can i force it to wait?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira already tried that the function is returning without value then ==> the programm is crashing

Comment: what is the crash error message?

Answer (score 3):

Any query is a promise,  you can return the promise. Something like:

const promise = query.once...
return Promise.all([promise]).

Maybe you dont need the array and just:

return promise;

This video should help https://youtu.be/NgZIb6Uwpjc

Answer (score 1):

From your comments maybe this is what you want to do:

```
const query = firebase.database().ref("/posts").orderByChild('postid').equalTo(1);
query.once('value', snapshot=>{
  if (snapshot && (snapshot.val() === "XYZ")){
    console.log("true");
    // do something
  }
  else {
    console.log("false");
    // do something else
  }
});
```

You need to check that **snapshot** is not null.

Note, if your code is in a function that is returning a value it won't work in the way you expect (i.e. it will always return false) because the query is an asynchronous call, so execute your logic within the query.

Answer (score 1):

heres a snippet that might help:

```
  //DETECTS DUPLICATE DISPLAY NAMES IN USERS BRANCH OF REALTIME DATABASE
  function displayNameExists (email, displayName, password){
    var users = db.ref('users');
    var duplicate = users.orderByChild('displayName').equalTo(displayName);
    duplicate.once('value').then(function(snap) {
      if(snap.val()){
        promptDuplicateName(displayName);
      } else {
        email = email;
        displayName = displayName;
        if(ls){
          localStorage.setItem('displayName', displayName);
        }else{
          // unavailable
        }                
        demoLogin.registerUsername(password);
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // The Promise was rejected.
      toast(error);
    });
  }
```